# Is it possible to reference systems.io.compression?

Tags: .net, vba, gzip

I am trying to uncompress a webresponse that I receiving gzip compressed. I tried setting Accept-Encoding headers to hopefully not receive the compressed JSON string, but it didnt work and I am convinced that the server forces gzip compression on the response.

I am using this as part of an EXCEL spreadsheet.

> the xmlhttprequest object does not have native uncompression. But
>   there are .NET libraries that in system.io.compression for a
>   GZipstream class.

I haven't been able to add a reference to the system.dll that this class exists in.

Is it possible?
Can anyone guide me on how to get this done?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you'll have to wrap the library with your own COM-visible .net type library. FWIW managed DLL's can't be directly referenced by VBA AFAIK - use the .tlb instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help in your case, but here is some VBA to Unzip files.

```
Public Sub UnzipFiles(FName As Variant, FileNameFolder As Variant, sFilter As String)
  Dim fso As Object
  Dim oApp As Object
  Dim DefPath As String
  Dim strDate As String
  Dim fileNameInZip As Variant

  Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

  For Each fileNameInZip In oApp.Namespace(FName).Items
    If LCase(fileNameInZip) Like LCase(sFilter) Then
      If Dir(FileNameFolder & "\" & oApp.Namespace(FName).Items.Item(CStr(fileNameInZip))) = "" Then
        oApp.Namespace((FileNameFolder)).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(FName).Items.Item(CStr(fileNameInZip))
      End If
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Im not sure what it does - how does it unzip files?

Comment: @brax I think you misunderstood the question.  This is not going to decompress a web response.